# нужна помощь с задачей

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть задача. не уверен что правильно все сделал. на ввод получаем число X. на выходе должен получиться ответ на следующую формулу(см.картинку):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
divider_subtrahend = 1
divident_subtrahend = 1 
divident = 0
divider = 0
x = int(input("Введите число X: "))
for i in range(2, 8):
    divider_subtrahend *= 2
    divident_subtrahend = divider_subtrahend - 1
    divident += x - divident_subtrahend
    divider += x - divider_subtrahend
print(divident / divider)
```

Comment: и?... вы хотели задать какой-то вопрос?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `x = int(input())
print(((x - 63)*(x - 31)*(x - 15)*(x - 7)*(x - 3)*(x - 1))/((x - 64)*(x - 32)*(x - 16)*(x - 8)*(x - 4)*(x - 2)))`

Answer (score 1):

```py
p = 1
up, down = 1, 1

x = int(input("Введите число X: "))
for i in range(2, 8):
    p *= 2
    up *= (x - (p - 1))
    down *= (x - p)

try:
    print(up / down)
except:
    print(f"{up} / {down}, нельзя делить на ноль")
```

Comment: "При вводе нечетного числа менее 63 будет 0" - нет. "при вводе четного числа менее 64 будет ошибка." - тоже нет. Легко проверяется.